# AngularJS: how to generate dynamic ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My current scenario is:
I've doing nesting repetition like follow:

```
<form name="task_form" ng-app="myApp" ng-submit="tasksubmit()">    
 <ul class="items-list">
      <li ng-repeat="task in taskslist | orderBy:orderProp">
      <p>
        <strong>{{task.title}}</strong>
      </p>
      <select name="task_value" ng-model="task.dropdown_value" class="select-box">
        <option ng-repeat="item in task.dropdown_values" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
      </select>
     </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

In `<li>` I'm repeating the `<option>` too. I want to generate the dynamic `ng-model` values in `<select ng-model="">`.. So that i can get them in controller.. and distinguish them via their `task.id`.

Comment: what is the issue with your code ?

Comment: @WasimMulla @dreamweiver .. here i have `tasklist` array of more then one hundred tasks. and each task contain `dropdown` and having some values. when i submit the form then via upper coding i can't get the submited or selected `dropdown_value` for `dropdown` against the `task.id` for next use to send as done tasks..

Comment: @dreamweiver Sir, waiting for your reply if u can do this...

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a dynamic value to ng-model is not an Ideal way,
what you can do is write a specific name to the ng-model (below)

```
<select name="task_value" ng-model="dropdown_value" class="select-box" ng-change="checkTaskId(task.id)">
```

you can even use a ng-change to the select element and traverse through your object using a loop and check the value according to the task.id, but in your controller itself.

Else if you really need the ng-model to be dynamic then below is an easy and alternate solution.

```
<select name="task_value" ng-model="myData.values[task.dropdown_value]"  class="select-box">
```

in yout controller you can have it like

```
$scope.myData= {
    values:{}
};
```

There are various other ways to do so. ways change according to your requirement. Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Help is really appreciable but I'm confused bro how to use it to get the `task.dropdown_values` selected value as well as `task.id` for this any specific task. Let me tell you about my array. `"taskslist":[{"id":"20","title":"Snow Level on Deck","type":"Dropdown","dropdown_values"
:[{"id":"55","value":"demo value"},{"id":"56","value":"less then 1 ft."},{"id":"57","value":"1 to 2 ft"
},{"id":"58","value":"2+ ft"}]}]` please have look on this array. how can i get the `item.id` along `with task.id` via your suggested `ng-model="myData.values[task.dropdown_value]"`

Comment: try using ng-options in select element as below

`<select class="form-control"  ng-options="item.value for item in taskslist.dropdown_values track by item.id" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="checkvalue(task.id, item.id)"></select>`

This is pass both the values with every change of select drop down. if the solution cannot suffice the resolution please create a plunker example i will solve it.

Comment: Sir, Can i use this `ng-model="myData.values[task.dropdown_value,task.id]"`. ? I'm creating plunker too.

Comment: I have created a plunker for you where you will get live preview of every value (item id, item value) with its task id.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HsWh2rWO6lO0CGQecRPw?p=preview

Hope this resolves your issue

Comment: sir, check my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1UJdMyc2eURfpHgIVkma?p=preview) too ...

Comment: Sir, Check my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1UJdMyc2eURfpHgIVkma?p=preview) too..